# How to make timer/program open only after pressing key instead of immediately?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I need to make this clock open only after pressing a key, lets say "t". Now it opens immediately after running it.

```
import tkinter as tk

def update_timeText():
    if (state):
        global timer
        timer[2] += 1
    if (timer[2] >= 100):
        timer[2] = 0
        timer[1] += 1
    if (timer[1] >= 60):
        timer[0] += 1
        timer[1] = 0
    timeString = pattern.format(timer[0], timer[1], timer[2])
    timeText.configure(text=timeString)
    root.after(10, update_timeText)

def start():
    global state
    state=True

state = False
root = tk.Tk()
root.wm_title('Simple Kitchen Timer Example')

timer = [0, 0, 0]
pattern = '{0:02d}:{1:02d}:{2:02d}'

timeText = tk.Label(root, text="00:00:00", font=("Helvetica", 50))
timeText.pack()

startButton = tk.Button(root, text='Start', command=start)
startButton.pack()

update_timeText()
root.mainloop()
```

It is in another program so as I have my graphics window I will press "t" and the clock will open.

Answer (score 0):

Keyboard is a python module that can detect keystrokes. Install it by doing this command.

```
pip install keyboard
```

Now you can do this.

```
while True:
           try: 
               if keyboard.is_pressed('t'):
                   state = True 
               elif(state != True):
                   pass
            except:
                state = False
                break #a key other than t the loop will break
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to organize the code little bit, like class structure. One possible implementation would be like that:

```
import tkinter as tk
TIMER = [0, 0, 0]
PATTERN = '{0:02d}:{1:02d}:{2:02d}'


class Timer:
    def __init__(self, master):
        #I init some variables
        self.master = master
        self.state = False

        self.startButton = tk.Button(root, text='Start', command=lambda: self.start())
        self.startButton.pack()

        self.timeText = tk.Label(root, text="00:00:00", font=("Helvetica", 50))
        self.timeText.pack()

    def start(self):
        self.state = True
        self.update_timeText()

    def update_timeText(self):
        if (self.state):
            global TIMER
            TIMER[2] += 1
        if (TIMER[2] >= 100):
            TIMER[2] = 0
            TIMER[1] += 1
        if (TIMER[1] >= 60):
            TIMER[0] += 1
            TIMER[1] = 0
        timeString = PATTERN.format(TIMER[0], TIMER[1], TIMER[2])
        self.timeText.configure(text=timeString)
        self.master.after(10, self.update_timeText)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = tk.Tk()
    root.geometry("900x600")
    root.title("Simple Kitchen Timer Example")
    graph_class_object = Timer(master=root)
    root.mainloop()
```

So clock will start when you click to button. If you want to start the clock by pressing "t" in keyboard, you need to bind that key to your function.
You can also add functionality if you want to stop the clock when you click to the button one more time.

**EDIT:**
if you also want to start to display the clock by clicking the button, you can move the code for initializing the `label` in to start function.

```
def start(self):
   self.state = True
   self.timeText = tk.Label(root, text="00:00:00", font=("Helvetica", 50))
   self.timeText.pack()
   self.update_timeText()
```